# Nonempty subsets of an inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following problem about inner product spaces:

Let $A$ and $B \supset A$ be nonempty subsets of an inner product space $X$. Show that:

a) $A \subset A ^{\perp\perp}  $

b) $B^\perp \subset A ^\perp $

I don't know how to solve this one. Thanks

Comment: Write down the definition of $M^\perp$. Look at it. Write down what $A^{\perp\perp}$ therefore is. See that all elements of $A$ have the defining property.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, if $x \in A$ and $y \in A^\perp$, we have $(x,y) = 0$ by the definition of $A^\perp$. Since $y \in A^\perp$ is arbitrary, we have $x \in (A^\perp)^\perp$ by the definition of $S^\perp$ with $S = A^\perp$.

For the second part, if $x \in B^\perp$ and $y \in A$, we have $y \in B$ since $A \subset B$ and therefore $(x,y) = 0$ by the definition of $B^\perp$. Since $y \in A$ is arbitrary, we have $x \in A^\perp$ by the definition of $A^\perp$.